# Multipart Question - in the Following Js Code how do I concatonate AssetCardName onto the Id

Tags: javascript

I have created a module class that will act as a template for displaying Assets, in a Card format within the html page, but have a few questions that i'm not 100% sure about..

ie
**1)** Are Self invoking functions valid inside of a modules & a class as-in the way i have written it below? I would like for the script to Automatically generate an Asset card every time `Card = new AssetCard()` is called with the relevant inputs. & insert this into the DOM in the correct Area of the page.
&
2) How do I properly concatonate the Assets_Card_Name declared in `this.card_name` onto the Id of the Container element. I have tried multiple methods, and it keeps saying `missing ) after arguments list`. even when I tried to use string literals.

```
export default class AssetCard {
    constructor(Asset_Card_Name, Asset_Type, License,
                      Creator, Vendor, XLink, AssetDate, JsonIndex,
                      Preview) {      // Constructor
        this.card_name = Asset_Card_Name;   // ::>> The Name of the Resource for that specific Card.
        this.type      = Asset_Type;        // ::>> Svg, 3D Model, Code, Fonts, Asset Crate, Pdf, Tutorial etc..
        this.licence   = License;           // ::>> Public Domain, Share Alike, MiT, Not Specified, etc....
        this.creator   = Creator;
        this.vendor    = Vendor;            // ::>> This Website or External Src such a Wikimedia, PublicDomainImages, ShutterStock etc..
        this.xLink     = XLink;             // ::>> XPath or Url......
        this.date      = AssetDate;         // ::>> Upload or Creation Date.
        this.jsonIndex = JsonIndex;         // ::>> File info....
        this.preview   = Preview;           // ::>> is the item previewable inside the browser?
    // ::>> Methods ::>>.........................<<
    // ::>> x
    (function createContainerObj(){
        // Select the right container from the page.........
        // Create A Div Element for the Card to be nested in,
        let CContainer = document.createElement("div");
            CContainer.setAttribute("id", "XCard-" + ${Asset_Card_Name});
        // Select the right section to be nested ie, tutorials, pdf, vectors, 3d, textures etc....
        // Grab the Asset_Type from above, & select the right area from the Dom.
    })();
        function flip3D(){
            // ::>> Flip Card & Show meta Data on reverse of Card? <<:: DoubleClick/Tap or Hover?
            document.getElementById(`XCard-` + ${Asset_Card_Name}).addEventListener("mouseenter",(e) => {
                // ::>> Todo...
                this.style.transform = `rotateX(180deg)`;
                // or e.traget?
                // ::>> Transition + preserve 3D...
            });
        }
        function openExternalSrc(){
            // ::>> Opens in new Browser Tab.
            //      fetch()
        }
        function addToFavs(){
            // ::>>
        }
        function download(){
            //
        }
        function share(){
            //
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: did you mean to create a class with no methods?

Comment: @jaromanda-x its just a draft or template at the moment, only posted this question because it was stored in the cache, before i could post a new one.. Will Correct or delete it later..

Comment: @jaromanda-x it has 5 methods, just no script inside these yet.

Comment: no, it does not, all your `function` are inside the `constructor`

Comment: @jaromanda-x I wasn't 100% sure about that, but sublime text editor was not syntax highlighting them functions if i moved it down one bracket, which is why i placed them where they currently are. Still trying to learn about classes and constructors.. Thanks for the info.

Comment: specifically its not highlighting the function keyword in blue? as it usually does...